# Mef Prism v4 - [Import] vs [ImportingConstructor]

Tags: c#, prism, mef, prism-4

When using MEF and Prism v4, what is the recommend way to do `[Import]`s and what is the difference (if anyway) between these two calls?

Option 1:

```
public class TestClass
{
    [Import]
    private IRegionManager _RegionManager;

    public TestClass()
    {
        // stuff here
    }
}
```

Option 2:

```
public class TestClass
{
    private IRegionManager _RegionManager;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public TestClass(IRegionManger regionManager)
    {
        this._RegionManager = regionManager;
        // stuff here
    }
}
```

What are the differences between these? Which is recommended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a matter of style but I'm a much bigger fan of `ImportingConstructor` than `Import` on fields.  The `ImportingConstructor` allows you to define an object which is both usable with and without MEF support.  The contract is clear and well understood by programmers.

Using `Import` on the other hand makes your class much more usable from MEF.  Developers are used to providing dependencies of an object to the constructor, not looking at all properties of an object and determining which ones it needs to set after construction.

Comment: Ok thanks, I was mixing and matching in my code and realized I should probaly go either `[ImportingConstructor]` or `[Import]`. Guess there isn't really much of a diff, just Prism or MEF styles. Going to see if anyone else has some comments on it, if not I'll mark yours as the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

with [ImportingConstructor] you can access your import in your constructor. with [Import] you can savely access your import at IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification.OnImportsSatisfied()

i would recommend [ImportingConstructor] and btw the public field should be private :)

Comment: Thanks for the info, and yes in my actual program they are private, let me change the post though for anyone who finds it with the same questions I had. So with [Import], they would not be available in the Constructor? Any difference when Lazy<> loaded?